Salesforce AppExchange Integration: Handling CRUD/FLS Checks for Guest User in Security Review
We are developing an app for the Salesforce AppExchange, and the core functionality of the app involves integration with external systems. During the Salesforce Security Review, we encountered an issue related to the CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) and FLS (Field-Level Security) requirements for Apex code. The guidelines specify that CRUD/FLS checks are mandatory for all Apex code to pass the security review.
However, in our case, the guest user does not have full access to Salesforce metadata, and we are unable to assign a permission set to the guest user because of their restricted permissions. Additionally, our app includes error logging, which requires access to Salesforce metadata, and we are running into difficulties ensuring the necessary access levels for the guest user to comply with the review.
Key questions:

Work around the guest user access restrictions while still complying with CRUD/FLS checks.
Determine if this can be marked as a false positive during the security review, or if there is another best practice we can implement.


It should be marked as false positive

If apex code is getting executed without CRUD & FLS, you would need to add these in false positive doc mentioned here.
Although there is no particular format for false positive doc, Salesforce recommends this template.
Also you can find example of responses here.
